# QT Creator keeps complaining it can't find .hg directory after moving project from mercurial to git

Tags: git, qt, mercurial

I've been working on an (open source) QT project that was previously using mercurial for source control. The project has moved onto using git. Or at least is moving onto git.

So I have taken a copy of the project and used hg2git to generate a git directory (pro tem) and then removed the .hg directory. Now whenever I open the (copy of the) project with QT Creator it complains that it can't find the .hg directory. This isn't particularly surprising given it isn't there, but I can't find anywhere I can change to tell QT Creator that this particular project isn't using mercurial.

Is there some project setting I'm missing? I have other projects still using mercurial and don't want to switch it off for everything.

Comment: manual way would be to check the *.pro.user file..

Comment: I did but i can't find anything obvious, like 'hg' or 'mercurial' in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found it at last, by some divide and conquer

One of the subprojects had this its .pro file

```
HG_VERSION=$(system hg id)
```

so I removed that for now, I'n not quite sure what the git equivalent would be as this has now broken up into multiple projects, but that's a different kettle of fish

Answer (score 0):

According to [QT Creator Docs](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-version-control.html)

> Qt Creator uses the version control system's command line clients to
>   access your repositories. To allow access, make sure that the command
>   line clients can be located using the PATH environment variable or
>   specify the path to the command line client executables in **Tools** >
>   **Options** > **Version Control**.

You have to have Git-client accessible and eliminate access to hg.exe - if Mercurial is single VCS, accessible by Creator, it tries to use it for VCS-tasks.

Or, because

> The **Tools** menu contains a submenu for each supported version control system

you just **tried to use Mercurial**?

Comment: Mercurial works fine. Git works fine. 

It's this ONE project which used to be mercurial and QT thinks it should be using mercurial.

Are you saying I have to remove mercurial from my system to shut this up, because that's terrible

Comment: @TomTanner - no, just check your current settings in Tools-Options-Version Contol and PATH

Comment: I removed mercurial from my path and now *all* my projects complain that hg is not the name of a .bat, .com or .exe file